# How can I pass in url arguments to an APIRequestFactory put request?

Tags: python, django, rest, testing

I have been trying for hours but cannot figure out how to pass a url argument through an APIRequestFactory put request. I have tried it through Postman when running my server and the url variable is passed just fine, but when I run it in my tests it stops working.

What I mean is that when I send a Postman PUT request to '/litter/1/' it will successfully take in the 1 as the variable litterId since my url is setup like this

```
path('litter/', include('apps.litter.urls')),
```

and

```
path('<int:litterId>/', LitterView.as_view(), name='litter-with-id')
```

But when I try and send an APIRequestFactory put request to that same url, for some reason the 1 will not go through as the litterId anymore.

Some relevant pieces of code...

My top level url.py

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views

from apps.litter.views import LitterView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('apps.my_auth.urls')),
    path('litter/', include('apps.litter.urls')),
]
```

This is my app specific urls.py

```
from .views import LitterView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', LitterView.as_view(), name='standard-litter'),
    path('<int:litterId>/', LitterView.as_view(), name='litter-with-id'),
]
```

Here is my views.py

```
import json
  
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.db import models

from .models import Litter
from .serializers import LitterSerializer


#@csrf_exempt
class LitterView(APIView):
    """ 
    View for litter related requests

    * Requres token auth
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]

    def put(self, request, litterId=0):
        """
        Updates an old litter
        """

        try:
            litterModel = Litter.objects.get(user=request.user, id=litterId)
        except Litter.DoesNotExist:
            returnData = {'status': 'fail',
                          'error': 'Could not find object with that id.'}
            return Response(returnData)

        serializer_class = LitterSerializer
        serialized = LitterSerializer(litterModel, data=request.data)

        if serialized.is_valid():
            litterModel = serialized.save()

            returnData = {'status': 'okay',
                          'litter': [serialized.data]}
            return Response(returnData)
        else:
            return Response(serialized.errors, status=400)
```

And here is the relevant test.

```
def test_easy_successful_put_type(self):
        """
        Testing a simple put
        """

        user = UserFactory()
        amount = 40
        amountChange = 20
        litter = LitterFactory(user=user, amount=amount)

        data = {'typeOfLitter': litter.typeOfLitter,
                'amount': litter.amount + amountChange,
                'timeCollected': litter.timeCollected}

        url = '/litter/' + str(litter.id) + '/'
        request = self.factory.put(url, data, format='json') 
        force_authenticate(request, user=user)
        view = LitterView.as_view()
        response = view(request).render()
        responseData = json.loads(response.content)
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get the int:litterId to get passed in, the put function always has the default value of 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
response = view(request).render()
```

You are manually passing the request to the view, also not passing the kwarg litterId, instead use `APIClient` and make a put request to the url. First import the required modules:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
```

then:

```
user = UserFactory()
amount = 40
amountChange = 20
litter = LitterFactory(user=user, amount=amount)
data = {
            'typeOfLitter': litter.typeOfLitter,
            'amount': litter.amount + amountChange,
            'timeCollected': litter.timeCollected
       }

url = reverse('litter-with-id', kwargs={'litterId': litter.id})
client = APIClient()
client.force_authenticate(user=user)
response = client.put(url, data, format='json')
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. I have been struggling with this for a while. Just to be sure, there's no way to do this with the request factory because it doesn't pass any data through the url you pass it?

Comment: @AdamBerard You can see the Request Factory only made the request for you, you had to call the correct view yourself, etc. You would have to manually pass the parameters like `response = view(request, litterId=litter.id).render()`.

Comment: Again thank you so much for your help. I'm always amazed at how helpful random strangers can be on the internet.